# Flexible project references in Visual Studio

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2008, dependency-management

I'm looking at migrating a very large code base, mostly C++ into SVN from VSS.  As part of that exercise I want to divide up the code into much smaller projects so they can be worked on individually.  The biggest stumbling block is dealing with project dependencies, where one project needs dlls (and headers) from other projects.

Currently developers get the required projects from VSS and build them locally, the project files assume everything that is needed has been checked out and is relative to that.  It's obviously a nightmare, especially when different versions of things are required.

For the past years I've been spoilt by maven and my past large scale C++ has been on UNIX and Linux.   I've looked into things like nuget but it's been decided to try and keep the solution down to just using SVN and visual studio build files.

My preferred solution was to use SVN externals to provide the project with the headers and binaries it needs from a tag and have the project refer to those via a variable.  That is straight forward enough, the issue I have is when a change is required in on of the projects that it is dependent one, e.g. a library change.

Say I have a project called Product1 and another called CommonLib1.  What I hoped to do was to provide the project file for Product1 reference CommonLib1 via a variable with a default of that referencing the SVN external provided files.  Then when a change in CommonLib1 is required the developer could check out that project, load it into their workspace, add the dependency in visual studio and that project would define the same variable that would override that set in Product1.

The nearest I can get seems to be to set an environment variable to override the setting but that requires manual setup and VS restarts.  I'd like to make things as automatic as possible to make life easier, partially for inexperienced developers/new to the project, but also for existing developer so they can just get on with the work and get a higher velocity going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely failed to implement this as I wanted too.  Instead I simply added svn:externals to the tags for the dependent projects.  It works, but a a bit clunky when working on multiple projects.